# Calling the same function for multiple objects in C#

Tags: c#

How can I use a function in C# that accepts the object as a parameter?

e.g., I have many checkboxes in a form all of which runs the same procedure, but I do not want to write the same function call inside each of the checkbox events:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        callMyFunction();
    }
}
```

What I want is to create an event handler that listens to all of checkbox objects registered to my event. Whenever a checkBox_CheckedChanged event is triggered, my function runs.

Comment: What argument are you expecting to be passed to `callMyFunction`? Your current example won't compile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the checkbox is the one raising the event, then `sender` should be the checkbox. You can check the type of `sender` and use that instead of explicitly naming the checkbox:

```
private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
    if(cb != null and cb.Checked)
    {
        callMyFunction(cb);
    }
}
```

You can then add this same handler to all your checkboxes e.g.

```
checkBox1.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_CheckedChanged;
checkBox2.CheckedChanged += CheckBox_CheckedChanged;
...
```

Comment: +1. I'd also advise the OP to rename the event handler to something less generic :)